# 'missing required :bucket option' in S3 paperclip rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I followed the instructions from this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

And am getting the following error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (missing required :bucket option):
```

and it points to the line:

```
<%= image_tag company.profile_image.url %>
```

These are what my current files look like

env.rb:

```
ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] = 'goodlifecompanyimages'
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'XXX'
ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'XXX'
```

development.rb:

```
 Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you are getting the error in production environment(on `heroku`) or development?